# Mobile image carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

Can anyone recommend a mobile image carousel that will resize images full screen depending on the handset resolution?  Ideally HTML5/Jquery based.
We don't need thumbnails - just purely a swipe screen of each image.

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Have you tried the plugin by Filament Group? http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/

Answer (score 2):

[PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) or [RoyalSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/royalslider-touchenabled-jquery-image-gallery/461126) might be what you are looking for!